# Error Encountered During Chainlink Dependency Installation with Foundry

Tags: chainlink, foundry

I'm running 'forge install smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.8.0 --no-commit' to install Chainlink dependencies, but I encountered the following error:

'error: 2871 bytes of body are still expected MiB | 300.00 KiB/s
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
fatal: clone of 'https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts' into submodule path '/home/elyas6126/foundry-f23/fund-me/lib/chainlink-brownie-contracts' failed
Error:
git submodule exited with code 128'.

please help me

Comment: This Error Code 128 looks like it may have to do with your authentication locally for git?
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Getting-code-128-fatal-detected-dubious-ownership-in-repository/qaq-p/2373506

Or judging by the first part it could be to do with your network stability?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66366582/github-unexpected-disconnect-while-reading-sideband-packet

i'd check the second part first and then check the first.  This doesnt look like a foundry repo issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue installing chainlink brownie smartcontract kit.The solution to it was I first cleared the Git cache

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m "Clear Git Cache"
```

Then cd into the lib folder and clone the repository manually

```
git clone https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts.git
```